# if statement to check number of days in a month

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing a simple program in asp.net mvc5 that will display a calendar. I have an array that stores the months and days 1-31. I would like to use an if statement to check for the month to allow only the appropriate number of days. I am really new to mvc and would appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime structure has a static method that gives you back how many days you have in a particular month of a specific year

```
 int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2014,2);
```

[MSDN DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So in this example, you are passing (2014, 2) but if you are testing for each month, would you code for each month? (2014, 1) (2014, 2), etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the if statement then your code may look like the below one.

```
@if ("JAN") {
   //Write your logic for populating dates
}
else if("FEB") {
    //Write your logic for populating dates for feb
}
else if("MAR") {
}
.
.
.
else
{
}
```

However you can also use the Switch statement for this as well.

```
@switch (Month in Integer)
    {
        case 0: 
                 <div>//Write your logic to populate the dates</div>
                 break;
        case 1: 
                 <span>Write your logic to populate the dates</span>
                 break;
    }
```